# Ci sono differenze di uso o di significato tra "acuire" e "acutizzare"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, verbs, word-meaning, difference

Nel racconto *La radura* di Marisa Madieri ho letto questa frase:

> "L'allergia s'era *acuita* procurandole febbre da fieno e violenti attacchi d'asma, che le impedivano perfino di parlare."

Non conoscevo questo verbo, "acuire"; io là avrei usato il verbo "acutizzare". Per questa ragione vi chiedo: c'è qualche differenza di uso o qualche sfumatura di significato che distingua questi due verbi, "acuire" e "acutizzare"?

Comment: Non mi sovviene nessun caso in cui non si possano usare indifferentemente. Forse "acuire" è un termine leggermente più colto.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Il verbo *acuire* viene dato dal De Mauro come [nato nel XIV secolo](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/lemma/1761/acuire), mentre *acutizzare* è riferito al [1901](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/lemma/1784/acutizzare).

Personalmente, userei *acutizzare* solo in senso medico, ma è adoperato anche come sinonimo di *acuire*.

Di sicuro *acutizzare* è più “facile da capire”, per via del suffisso *-izzare*, ma, come tutti i verbi di questo tipo è anche più brutto (sempre meno del derivato *acutizzazione*, naturalmente) e dannoso perché riduce la ricchezza lessicale della lingua.

I gerghi tecnici, come quello medico, hanno bisogno di termini più precisi di quelli generici come *acuire*  che letteralmente sarebbe “dare/prendere la forma di ago”: *il dolore si è acuito* significa che lo percepisco come un ago che mi punge e fa più male. Un medico parlerebbe di “dolore acutizzato” per indicare una specifica caratteristica sintomatologica.

L'esempio del De Mauro *la crisi ha acutizzato i problemi* sarebbe molto meglio reso con *la crisi ha acuito i problemi*.

Comment: +1, d'accordo su tutto. Strano che il De Mauro (o almeno la sua versione in rete) non chiarisca l'accezione tecnica, e più propria, medica di “acutizzare, -rsi” nel senso di “diventare acuto” contrapposto a cronico.

Comment: Sono arrivato qui perché ho letto _acutizzare_ in una traduzione in Italiano di 1984 di George Orwell. E sì, _acuire_ suonerebbe molto meglio.